# Split nested Tables and combine them

Tags: list-manipulation

I am doing a research and found that the time efficiency of Nested `Table` in MMA isn't quite well but if you can break it into two single `Table` it will be much faster.

For example, for two matrix

```
matA = RandomInteger[10, {12, 12}];
matB = RandomInteger[10, {12, 12}];
```

This one is slower, but gives my desired result:

```
Table[(matA + i)*(matB + j), {i, 0, 3}, {j, -3, 3}] // RepeatedTiming// First
```

> Result: 0.0000503 second

If you break the above Table into two parts, each of them will calculate pretty fast:

```
Table[(matA + i), {i, 0, 3}] // RepeatedTiming// First
Table[(matB + j), {j, -3, 3}] // AbsoluteTiming // First
```

> Result:2.677*10^-6 and 4.482*10^-6 , and the total time of both is 7.159*10^-6 second

But I don't know if it was possible to get the same result as the original nested one by breaking it into two parts like above example? If yes,then how to manipulate this two separate tables to acquire same desired result as the original one delivered?  Thanks for the reading and help in advance!

Comment: For such short times, you should use [`RepeatedTiming`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RepeatedTiming.html) instead of [`AbsoluteTiming`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AbsoluteTiming.html).

Comment: The first table has $4\times 7=28$ elements, while the last tables have $4+7=11$ elements. You are computing different objects -- no wonder the timings are different.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, so there is no way to solve this problem by two separate Tables?

Comment: Yes, you would have to take the Cartesian product thereof. But that would take some time too, and you'd be back to the initial timing.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is too localized; i.e, it applies only to the local situation and needs of its poster and answers will not benefit others.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Outer`:

```
(t1 = Table[(4 + i)*(5 + j), {i, 0, 3000}, {j, -3000, 3000}]) // AbsoluteTiming // First
(t2 = Table[(4 + i), {i, 0, 3000}]) // RepeatedTiming // First
(t3 = Table[(5 + j), {j, -3000, 3000}]) // RepeatedTiming // First
(t4 = Outer[Times, t2, t3]) // AbsoluteTiming // First
{%%%%, % + %% + %%%}
(* {0.5, 0.1} *)
t1 == t4
(* True *)
```

The naïve approach is five times slower. But you can only use `Outer` here because `t1` has rank one; I assume you already know this.

Comment: Thanks, for the answer,it seems that nested Table is the best